# How to deactivate internet search result in unity panel Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity

I mostly used my Ubnutu system for programming purpose and whenever I search something from unity panel it also display result from internet(I believe but not sure). I rarely used/clicked these search items, so Let me know if is their is any way to stop this.

Please follow the image for more clarity -

[image: unity image]

Comment: Buddy, you just need to click "filter results" and deactivate online results!

Comment: @EduardoCola aah thx a lot...really don't know about this, no shame in saying that I am using Ubuntu from more than 3 years and still exploring :)